# How to lower mat-icon with input in angular material?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

This is my code:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input type="tel" matInput placeholder="Home">
  <mat-icon matSuffix svgIcon="home" class="mdi-icon"></mat-icon>
</mat-form-field>
```

And this is the result:

[image]

As it is seen icon is to high and I want to lower it to decrease the distance between the bottom line and the icon. I tried:

```
  .mdi-icon {
    margin-bottom: -5px;
  }
```

But it didn't help. Could anyone say how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

For the CSS to have any effect on a child component you first need to first get around view encapsulation. View encapsulation will add a unique attribute to all of your HTML elements within the template, something like `_ngcontent-nvb-c74=""`, then it will append that identifier to all of your CSS like `[_ngcontent-nvb-c74]`. That is how the CSS of one component does not affect others.

---

We need to make the CSS **global**. So, we need to use a unique selector or else your CSS will leak into other components. I would use the component name personally. I'm using `app-my` as an example selector for the component `MyComponent`. So in all three cases your CSS will look like:

```css
app-my .mdi-icon {
   ...
}
```

Your options to get around View Encapsulation are:

**1. Disable View Encapsulation for the component - not usually recommended**

```js
@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class MyComponent {}
```

This makes **all** of the CSS in that component global, not great if you want view encapsulation in other areas of your component.

**2. Put your CSS in styles.css**

Any CSS in this file is global by default.

**3. Create a new global style file for this component**

Something like `my.component.global.css`

After creating this file you need to add it to the `styles` array in `angular.json`. Any CSS files in this array are applied globally, `styles.css` is the only one by default.

**angular.json**

```json
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/app/my.component.global.css"
            ],
```

If you're using scss, you can import this file into `styles.scss` instead of adding it to the `styles` array.

---

Now for actually moving the icon, I'm just using the non-svg icon but it should work the same

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input type="tel" matInput placeholder="Home" />
  <mat-icon class="mdi-icon">home</mat-icon>
</mat-form-field>
```

I removed `matSuffix`

```css
app-my .mdi-icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 5px;
}
```

In some cases you will be overriding other css already present in the child, to do that, you may need to increase the specificity by repeating a class (not necessary in this case)

```css
app-my .mdi-icon.mdi-icon.mdi-icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 5px;
}
```